# Perform an INNER JOIN only if the table being joined contains a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which gets the `user_id` from the table `profiles` where the **profile.status** is **wip/declined/cancelled** and where their **user_activity_log.last_activity** time was more than 1 minute ago:

```
SELECT t1.user_id 
FROM profiles t1 
INNER JOIN user_activity_log t2 
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
WHERE t1.status IN ('wip','declined','cancelled') 
    AND t2.last_activity < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

This works as expected however what I want to do now is include this:

```
INNER JOIN email_logs t3 
    ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id AND t3.sent_datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

But I only want this join to happen if the `user_id` exists in that table (`email_logs`) otherwise return the results from the initial query.

How would I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just use a `left outer join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `NOT EXISTS`, but the condition in the subquery changes slightly:

```
SELECT p.user_id 
FROM profiles p INNER JOIN
     user_activity_log ual
     ON p.user_id = ual.user_id 
WHERE p.status IN ('wip', 'declined', 'cancelled') AND
      ual.last_activity < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM email_logs el
                  WHERE p.user_id = el.user_id AND
                        el.sent_datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
                 )
```